# MEF for huge number of addins

Tags: c#, mono, add-in, mef

I am currently working on a C# based application which loads a lot of different modules (.net drivers for hardware components etc.). The application should offer some kind of plugin/add-in manager to select dedicated modules (only a dedicated group of devices, filters, component). Based on the fact that there is a well established framework MEF which comes out of the box from MS, I thought it would be a good idea to give it a try.

The main problem I am currently facing is the fact that after scanning folders for add-ins via the `DirectoryCatalog` all assemblies are loaded into the process (currently nothing is instantiated because I use the "Lazy" mechanism).

Nevertheless I want to avoid loading all the assemblies in the process when the user decides later on to pick only a few of them.

So I try to find a way to get the add-in metadata without keeping the assemblies loaded within the process. I have seen that the `Mono.Addins` framework seems to support such a scenario with XML based manifests - but I am not sure if something similar could be done with MEF?

Comment: If you don't want to keep the assemblies loaded, consider launching another process (even the same application with different arguments) to scan the assemblies and report back via inter-process communication. I'm unfamiliar with Mono Addins so I can't comment on that aspect of your question.

Comment: you can but you need to write your own catalog type

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [LazyAssemblyCatalog](https://github.com/lestera/LazyAssemblyLoading) exactly for this purpose.
It allows you to lazily load plugin assemblies, while still having access to their metadata.